smblibrary always returns status_logon_failure error and I can't understand the reason
I have literally been working on this issue for months, and I really, really need help.
The problem is that despite my credentials being correct and my timestamp settings being accurate, I always, always get the STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE error.
Normally, I can log into places that don’t require AD login (i.e., just username and password) and list the shares, but whenever I need to log in with AD, I get the STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE error right away.
You can find much more detailed information about this issue in the library's issue section. I am leaving the code I used and the link to the issue below.
You don’t necessarily have to solve the problem; I would be truly grateful if you could share even the slightest idea related to this issue. Thank you in advance. (this lab enviroment is "enterprise" machine on tryhackme. it's free, if you want to try the code you can deploy "enterprise" machine on tryhackme) Also, if you want I can provide pcap and event log files. just let me know if you want.
using SMBLibrary.Client;
using SMBLibrary;
using System.Net;
class test
{

    static void Main()
    {
        SMB2Client client = new SMB2Client(); // SMB2Client can be used as well
        bool isConnected = client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.10.254.242"), SMBTransportType.DirectTCPTransport);
        if (isConnected)
        {
            NTStatus status = client.Login("lab.enterprise.thm", "nik", "ToastyBoi!",AuthenticationMethod.NTLMv2);
            if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                List<string> shares = client.ListShares(out status);
                foreach (var share in shares)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(share);
                }
                client.Logoff();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(status.ToString());
            }
            client.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}

github link : https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary/issues/259
I tried fixing timestamp problems, I tried different AD enviroments and also I tried this credentials and code in different computers (I thought maybe there is something wrong with my computer.)

OK you are trying to authenticate to AD with NTLM not Kerberos. Are you sure this domain actually allows NTLM? For Kerberos, you need the following in order for it to work: use the FQDN not IP address, have line-of-sight from the client to the Domain Controller, the file server needs to have registered the correct SPN in the domain (usually automatic). For both NTLM and Kerberos you need to specify the username as SHORTDOMAIN\user or user@longdomain.com. Is there any reason you are not just using Kerberos with kinit?

@Charlieface thanks for answer. yeah I'm sure it supports ntlm and domain\username authentication. The key part is, same code works with TalAloni (you can see it in github discussion, I dropped link there  https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary/issues/259 ). He says "there is nothing wrong with library and code but I can't still understand why it doesnt work for you". You can also find event logs and wireshark files in the same github discussion or if you want you can try this code. I'm sure it won't work.
